# keytool : SHA256withRSA written instead of an actual SHA256 on my production keystore

Tags: android, keytool

I need to get the sha256 fingerprint for appsflyer.

However, when executing

> keytool -list -v -alias myaliad -keystore ./mykey.keystore

I get the following output, where, instead of an actual SHA256 value, I get "SHA256withRSA".

```
Nom d'alias : myapp
Date de création : 11 janv. 2017
Type d'entrée : PrivateKeyEntry
Longueur de chaîne du certificat : 1
Certificat[1]:
Propriétaire : CN=SomeDude, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Fr
Emetteur : CN=SomeDude, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Fr
Numéro de série : 583ebd9
Valide du : Wed Jan 11 19:03:04 CET 2017 au : Tue Dec 04 19:03:04 CET 2153
Empreintes du certificat :
         MD5 : *a correct md5 hash*
         SHA1 : *a correct sha1 hash*
         SHA256 : SHA256withRSA
Nom de l'algorithme de signature : Clé RSA 2048 bits
Algorithme de clé publique du sujet : 3
Version : {10}
```

What should I do to get the actual Sha256 fingerprint ?

Comment: Can you execute the command preceding with `LC_ALL=C; keytool ...` so we could get the english version?

Comment: @Pierre,  I had the same problem. I found your reply "funny" because the valid data is obviously there. I did it anyway. And it "fixed" the problem. It seems to be a translation issue. "SHA1" is actually "SHA256" This is from my observation at least.

Comment: I suspected a translation problem on the OP system (since SHA1 was irrelevant here), hence my reply ;)
Glad you confirmed it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take this with a grain of salt. This might be a bug in keytool for non english locales (French, German) Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong:

locale=de,system locale

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <pathToKeyStore>
...
Zertifikatfingerprints:
MD5: <FINGERPRINT>
SHA1: <FINGERPRINT>
SHA256: SHA256withRSA
```

Now in English:
locale=en

```
LANG=C keytool -list -v -keystore <pathToKeyStore>
...
Certificate fingerprints:
SHA1: <FINGERPRINT>
SHA256: <FINGERPRINT>
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
```

So the second fingerprint seems to "always" be the SHA256 fingerprint, only in the two, or more, mentioned locales "keytool" has a bug in the translation. I'm not an expert on this, but this is just a visual observation.

Comment: I've got the same error, too. My locale is de. Is there some sort of bugtracker, where we can report this bug?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using the keytool utility, however using "gradlew" directly it works.

Go to your project's app folder and run:

> ./gradlew signingReport

It will print all the signatures related to your app. Locate the one you are looking for (in my case, it was "release").

```
----------
Variant: release
Config: release
Store: ***
Alias: ***
MD5: ***
SHA1: ***
SHA-256: ***
Valid until: ***
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@CaptainCrunch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524355/captaincrunch) in the chosen answer, it seems that there is some sort of bug when displaying the information provided by this command. I am having the same problem now, almost 2 years ago, when displaying the information in Spanish. I noticed the keytool command showed inconsistent information compared to the Signing Report from Gradle so I started looking into which one was right and ended up here.

My solution was to change the language of the output via adding an argument in the command (`-J-Duser.language=en`):

```
keytool -J-Duser.language=en -list -v -alias myalias -keystore ./mykey.keystore
```

As an observation, not only the certificate fingerprints get shifted by one but the whole chain of results get shifted by one from the MD5 field, for example:

Correct result in English:

```
Creation date: aDate
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Issuer: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Serial number: 1
Valid from: aDate until: anotherDate
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: <FINGERPRINT>
         SHA256: <FINGERPRINT>
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 1
```

Shifted result in Spanish:

```
Fecha de Creación: aDate
Tipo de Entrada: PrivateKeyEntry
Longitud de la Cadena de Certificado: 1
Certificado[1]:
Propietario: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Emisor: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Número de serie: 1
Válido desde: aDate hasta: anotherDate
Huellas digitales del certificado:
         MD5: <FINGERPRINT>
         SHA1: <FINGERPRINT>
         SHA256: SHA256withRSA
Nombre del algoritmo de firma: Clave RSA de 2048 bits
Algoritmo de clave pública de asunto: 1
Versión: {10}
```

I think keytool is included in the JDK so I'll leave the JDK version I'm using just fyi: `openjdk version "1.8.0_372"`.